# my jquery animation function not working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

When the user hovers over the button, I am trying to change the button arrow image using the jquery animate function but it's not working. Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/YSGYz/6/) and this is my script.

```
$('.Button').mouseenter(function(){  
   $('.arrow-image').animate({  
       'background-image':'url(images/sp-images.png)',  
       'background-repeat':'no-repeat', 
       'background-position':'-85px -0px'
    },5000);  
});
```

Comment: You've posted 29 other questions, you should be reliably applying code formatting by now. Refer to the **How to Format** box shown to the right of the text area when asking/editing your question, and the **[?]** link above it.

Comment: Separately: Live links (to http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net) are a great *add on* to your question, but always include the relevant code/markup *in the question itself*. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: I don't believe that background-image and background-repeat are things that you can animate because they don't have a starting and ending value - they just have one value.  What exectly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: just change the arrow image slowly

Answer (score 1):

Hope, this piece of code would be of any help. I know, you have used background image for some purpose but i was trying to make the things work as expected with some other way around.  :) here is my try to make the arrow animate !

Made one change - rather using background image, i have used img tag.

check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/HvdZP/1/

Answer (score 0):

your 'background-position':'-85px -0px', change it to

```
'background-position-x':'-85px',
'background-position-y':'0px'
```

Answer (score 0):

XepterX is right:
http://jsfiddle.net/YSGYz/7/

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery documentation for `.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> Animation Properties and Values All animated properties should be
>   animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most
>   properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery
>   functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but
>   background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used).
>   Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise
>   specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.

From this one can see that you can't animate to a new image or to a repeat value.  You can animate style properties that are a number and a few other properties that are a number.  That's how jQuery `.animate()` works.

If you want to slowly change from one image to another, then you need two objects, one that is visible that is the old image and one that is not visible that is the new image.  You use CSS to make the two objects overlap exactly.  You can then use `.fadeIn()` on the new image and `.fadeOut()` on the old image.

As XepterX has shown, `background-position-x` and `background-position-y` are represented by a single number so they could be animated, but the image URL or the repeat value cannot be animated.